# Meteor - How to properly display spinner while template loads

Tags: meteor

I've got a template that has an intentional delay in it using http://deelay.me so I can test a slow server.

```
<template name="aboutPage">
  <img src="http://deelay.me/2000/http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02830/cat_2830677b.jpg">
</template>
```

On my router page:

```
Router.configure
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'

Router.route '/', name: 'homePage'
Router.route '/about', name: 'aboutPage'
```

loading template:

```
<template name="loading">
  {{> spinner}}
</template>
```

For some reason, when I hit the About page, I get a missing image icon as the image loads. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you checking this package: https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/iron-router-progress
It let's you delay the progress from showing up on fast routes.

```
Router.configure
    progressDelay : 100
```

Regarding the "missing image icon", I tried to reproduce the situation but I couldn't. However, I noticed that using the deelay.me technic won't work for testing the loading between routes. That's because aboutPage is already loaded when the image request starts. Therefore, the loading spinner already disappeared.

Check this repo por a simple example that actually tracks the image loading: https://github.com/humberaquino/meteor-imageloading-example

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I made it works with this.

```
Router.route('/about', {
  name: 'about',
  data: function() { 

    if(this.ready()){
      this.render()
    }else{
      this.render('loading')
    }
  }
});
```

Take a look, here we ensure that the all data on template is ready, if not we render the `'loading'` template.

That works for me

Comment: Does this still work? My spinner only shows up when I use waitOn: function () and disappears before the content fully load (might be because I'm on localhost). The thing is I have static templates that I don't have anything to subscribe to. Suggestions?